# Difference between directly providing ComponentStore and using provideComponentStore in Angular Standalone Components

Tags: angular, ngrx-store, angular-standalone-components, angular2-providers, ngrx-component-store

I'm working with standalone Angular components and experimenting with the NgRx Component Store. I'm facing confusion regarding the correct way to inject the component store into a component.
Here's how I've been providing the store in my component:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'example-selector',
    standalone: true,
    providers: [ExampleStore],
    templateUrl: './comparison-view.component.html',
    styles: [],
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ],
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {
...
}
```

However, I came across the **provideComponentStore** method in the [NgRx documentation](https://ngrx.io/guide/component-store/lifecycle):

```js
import { provideComponentStore } from '@ngrx/component-store';

@Component({
    selector: 'example-selector',
    standalone: true,
    providers: [provideComponentStore(ExampleStore)],
    templateUrl: './comparison-view.component.html',
    styles: [],
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ],
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {
...
}
```

Both methods seemed to work in my application, and I could utilize the store without any issues. What's the exact difference between these two approaches, and which one is recommended for my use case?

*Using Version 16.x of @ngrx/store*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt, always check [the source code](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/f2514baea9dd528a9f54f0623fe803b09b132c1e/modules/component-store/src/lifecycle_hooks.ts#L88) !

```
export function provideComponentStore<T extends object>(
  componentStoreClass: Type<ComponentStore<T>>
): Provider[] {
  const CS_WITH_HOOKS = new InjectionToken<ComponentStore<T>>(
    '@ngrx/component-store ComponentStore with Hooks'
  );

  return [
    { provide: CS_WITH_HOOKS, useClass: componentStoreClass },
    {
      provide: componentStoreClass,
      useFactory: () => {
        const componentStore = inject(CS_WITH_HOOKS);

        // Set private property that CS has been provided with lifecycle hooks
        componentStore['ɵhasProvider'] = true;

        if (isOnStoreInitDefined(componentStore)) {
          componentStore.ngrxOnStoreInit();
        }

        if (isOnStateInitDefined(componentStore)) {
          componentStore.state$
            .pipe(take(1))
            .subscribe(() => componentStore.ngrxOnStateInit());
        }

        return componentStore;
      },
    },
  ];
```

As you can see, this method will run the lifecycle hooks defined on the ComponentStore (as mentioned in [the docs](https://ngrx.io/api/component-store/provideComponentStore)).

Comment: So, this means, I only need to use the provideComponentStore()-function if I rely on calling the lifecycle hooks?
Any best practice opinions on this topic or other effects one might not know about?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `provideComponentStore()` method if you are planning to use lifecycle hooks such as `OnStoreInit`, `OnStateInit` or `OnDestroy`. See: https://ngrx.io/guide/component-store/lifecycle 
Also, if you do not register your component store using `provideComponentStore()` and you use one of the hooks, you will see warning in browser console. It's also mentioned in the docs:

> If you implement the lifecycle hooks in the ComponentStore, and register it with providers without using provideComponentStore(), in development mode, a warning is logged to the browser console.